# Resize div without giving an initial value

Tags: html, css, resize

Is it possible by using only css to resize a div without initial height 220px given as in example (to have a responsive div).
If I remove the initial height transition stops to work but div is stil resizing. How to keep transtion while removing 220px height condition.

I'm using the following code:

```css
.resize{
    height: 220px;
    width:auto;
    background: red;
    transition:         all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:    all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:      all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:     all 1.0s  ease-in-out;
}

.resize:hover{
    height: 340px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resize">
  This is resizable div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a height to its parent element, then you can use percentage heights to give the container a relative height.

for example:

```
<body>
    <div class="foo">
    This container will have a relative height
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    height: 500px;
}

foo{
    height:50%;
}
```

Comment: What about if body haight is defined as follow:
body {
 width: auto;
 height: 100%; }

Comment: The container must inherit a value in order to use a relative value of it. For example 100% of the value foo inherits from body = 500px